# Check Geometry - Bad Envelope

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I have a polygon feature which returns **Bad envelope** when run through the [Check Geometry tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/check-geometry.htm).

According to the help:

> Bad envelope : The envelope does not match the coordinate extent of
>   the geometry.

I'm not sure what this means. I tried googling feature envelopes but couldn't find anything discussing.

I ran a `Feature Envelope To Polygon` on the bad feature and The polygon created fit the polygon perfectly:

[image]

I checked the original polygon's extent min/max x/ys and they match the envelope polygon exactly.

```
>>> print inExt.YMin
13693868.258
>>> print envExt.YMin
13693868.258
>>> print inExt.YMax
13694050.7098
>>> print envExt.YMax
13694050.7098
>>> print inExt.XMin
1814653.01959
>>> print envExt.XMin
1814653.01959
>>> print inExt.XMax
1815376.21679
>>> print envExt.XMax
1815376.21679
```

**Question: What does it mean for a feature to have a bad envelope?**

Note: I ran a `Repair Geometry` on the feature. The tool indicates the envelope has been fixed, but after this is done a `Check Geometry` on the same feature returns **Bad envelope** still.

Comment: Is this a shapefile or file geodatabase, or some other format?

Comment: @Vince file geodatabase feature class.

Comment: Perhaps the envelope extends beyond the [projection horizon](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#400a2020-2590-4a27-ac99-726950d2d115.htm) even though the polygon itself doesn't, and CheckGeometry isn't robust enough to tell you that.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, but I've sometimes seen it happen when projection-on-the-fly is used with editing.  There could be corruption of the FGDB, so creating a new .gdb and copying the FC is certainly something to try. If it persists, then it's time to visit Tech Support.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall An interesting idea, but there are polygons to the north, south, east, and west of this polygon throwing the error, none of which have the same error given.

Comment: @Vince I made a new copy for the feature class in a new geodatabase and the same error was thrown.

Comment: Yeah, Tech Support time.

Comment: It does not look like a lot of vertices so can you provide some ArcPy code to generate it?

Comment: @PolyGeo I’m an end user of the data so I do not know how it was generated.

Comment: Can you read its vertices using ArcPy to ungenerate it back to ASCII?